# Jstree - Can't check checkboxes in AJAX call, works in classic call. An issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, plugins, jstree

I do an AJAX call for creating and populating my JSTree div. I activated the **checkbox** plugin and try to **check** all checkboxes within my AJAX result callback. It doesn't work.

I binded the same function (that will check all boxes) to a button and, here, it works.

I also tried to check all checkboxes through a **custom event** with jQuery but it doesn't do anything, as in the AJAX call

Is this an issue with JSTree or is there something that I'm missing?

I reproduced this *issue (?)* in JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyyn/c74wpa6z/

---

## Specs:

- jQuery 1.9.1
- jsTree 3.2.1

---

## The code

***HTML***

```
<h1>
JSTree Demo
</h1>
<button id="btn">
Check All
</button>
<div id="jstree">

</div>
```

***JS***

```
// Populate the tree with some generic data
$.ajax({
    // ... initial ajax code with some generic data
    success: function(response) {
            var $tree = $("#jstree");
            $tree.jstree(response);
        
        // Try to check all boxes, it doesn't work
        checkAll($tree);
    }
});

// Try to check all boxes, here it works. Why.
$("#btn").click(function(){
        checkAll($("#jstree"));
})

// This will check all boxes inside the tree
function checkAll(tree) {
        tree.jstree(true).check_all();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because jstree hasn't yet built the nodes when you call `checkAll` inside success callback. Just wrap your `checkAll` call into `ready.jstree` event like below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/c74wpa6z/6/).

```
...
success: function(response) {
    var $tree = $("#jstree");
    $tree.jstree(response).on('ready.jstree', function() {

        // Try to check all boxes
        checkAll($tree);

});
```